# How to set corner radius for pentagonal button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to set corner radius for pentagonal button. This the code for my         pentagonal usercontrol.I am new in wpf so i getting difficulties please help me out.

```
 < UserControl.Resources >
    <Style x:Key="Poly1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" BorderThickness="5" >
                    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                        <Polygon   Points="0,0 175,0 250,50 175,100 0,100          
          0,45" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="2" 
         Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                < /ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
 < /UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Replace the Polygon with a [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx) with appropriate arc segments in its geometry. See [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for reply.but is it not possible using polygon i can set the corner        radius.